# angular-ui accordion data closing on request

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, get, angularjs-ng-repeat, accordion, angular-ui

I am using angular bootstrap-ui to show an accordion. The data is being pull by making a timed interval get request to my back end. The is every time the data is pulled. if the accordion is open, it closes when a get request is made. How can i keep the accordion open when a get request is made?

```
                    <accordion>
                        <accordion-group  is-open="isopen"
                                          ng-repeat="data in person" 
                                          ng-controller="homeCtrl">
                            <accordion-heading >      
                                {{data.personName}} - {{isopen}}
                            </accordion-heading>
                            <div data-backdrop="static">{{data.lastName}}             </div>
                        </accordion-group>
                    </accordion>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to post more information before this could be answered. At a glance I'd say you could just make sure the "isopen" variable doesn't get set to "falsey" until after the $http.get promise object is resolved. Without seeing your controller it's tough to say, but promises are the best way to track your async requests like that.